# Use 100% of remaining height

Tags: html, amcharts

I'm creating an internal app so browser compatibility restrictions aren't a massive concern. I am using a div container that is using [jquery ui resizable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/) and therefore the size is unknown for any given div. I am also using a chart library (amCharts) which needs the parent div to have a height in order to render the chart.

The issue I'm facing is 100% within a div (with other elements in said div) means whilst the child div accepts 100% as verbatim and makes itself 100% of the parent div this isn't actually the intention - I want it to use the remaining space available in the div, rather than 100%.

I've tried table-row however that doesn't provide a height and therefore amcharts doesn't work well with any resizing (as it has no height/width to base itself on).

So I guess my question is, based on height, what is the best method of making a div use 100% of the remaining space, without JS and without using table/table-cell/table-row styles?

**Edit: Here's a JSFiddle of the issue:**
https://jsfiddle.net/2c8n1y04/

And the HTML:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b"><h3>Header</h3></div>
    <div class="c">
        <div id="chartdiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
html,body,.c,#chartdiv
{
    height:100%
}

.a {
    height:300px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.b {
    background-color: yellow;
}
h3 {
    margin:0;  
}
```

There is also a chart added in the JSFiddle using the amcharts library, this library is dependent on a height (otherwise it renders to 0 height). Also in the code base i'm using jquery-ui resizable ui (via [gridstack](http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/)) which means I am unable to define a height as the chart height simply has to stretch to the full remaining height within the div.

Comment: I suggest making an example so people can see what you are talking about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Any love for</s> Does your engine support `flex`?
That would in my eyes be the easiest and cleanest solution.

Apply to the parent:

```
flex-direction: column;
display: flex;
/* or, if a prefixed version is supported, one of: */
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
```

and to the child to be stretched:

```
flex: 1;
```

And you should be good to go.

Demo, if your browser supports it (click on "Full page" to see the effect)

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    border: solid 1px #333;
    padding: 5px;
}
#a {
    margin: 10px;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    flex-direction: column;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
#b {
    height: 100px;
    background: #FFE;
}
#c {
    flex: 1;
    background: #EFE;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">Fixed</div>
    <div id="c">Flexible</div>
</div>
```

But may I ask why you want a no-JS solution, since you're already using jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for the example, unfortunately flex isn't working (JSFiddle added of my original problem), essentially the amcharts library requires a height in the parent div or it doesn't work (at least thats how it seems!).

Comment: Legend, that worked perfectly - thank you, I'll accept your answer! For reference, updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/53nfLfcr/4/